# laravel internal server error

Tags: php, oop, laravel

how to configure .htaccess in laravel 4.2

this what I am using but I am getting internal server error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Laravel already ships with a [`.htaccess`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.2.11/public/.htaccess) file included in the `public` directory. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Check your error logs first and foremost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provide all information you want in its documentation.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```